# How to add an image on the bottom side of border repeatedly in which it should have a space between two images

Tags: html, css

"I am displaying an image as horizontal on the bottom side of the border for that what should i do?"

"I have written a simple code to display but it does not show which i really want to display."

This is my code

```
<div id="para3">
   <p>
       How to display a border image on the bottom 
    </p>

 </div>
<style type="text/css">

#para3 p{
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 2px;
    border-image:url('pic.jpg') 2 repeat;
}
</style>
```

i expect the output as shown in the image below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do that using `border-image`. It will be a hassle to get to work, - but if you want, then [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/) explains a bit about it.

I would do it using `background` on `#para3`, - and then positioning it in the bottom - and adding `padding-bottom` like so: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYgNqa 
... Controlling the spaces between the images are also a hassle, - so I would (again), make an image where the space was part of the image - and then just repeat that image. It would make it easier to work with, - and the code would be less cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only want a repeated dot at the bottom. Something you can easily do with a `radial-gradient`. You simply need to adjust the values of `background-size` and the radius of the circle to control the layout:

```css
p {
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
.one {
  background:radial-gradient(circle,#000 5px,transparent 6px) bottom left/12px 12px repeat-x;
}

.two {
  background:radial-gradient(circle,#000 5px,transparent 6px) bottom left/20px 12px repeat-x;
}
.three {
  background:radial-gradient(circle,#000 3px,transparent 4px) bottom left/25px 8px repeat-x;
}
.four {
  background:radial-gradient(circle,#000 1px,transparent 2.5px) bottom left/5px 5px repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">
  lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem 
</p>
<p class="two">
  lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum 
</p>
<p class="three">
  lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum 
</p>
<p class="four">
  lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum lorem pisum 
</p>
```